# How do I link my frontend server to an external backend server

Tags: hyperlink, frontend, connection, backend

I've completed my development of my fullstack website and wanted to switch over the apiBase from a localHost//Port name to a backend server hosted online on Heroku. However, when I switched from this.apiBase = 'http://localhost:3000' to this.apiBase = "mybackendservernamehere.herokuapp.com", I found from the console logs that it had requested from mybackendservernamehere.herokuapp.com//auth... for example instead of the standard mybackendservernamehere.herokuapp.com/auth.

May I know how to set up the link to not include the / by default so I do not have to change the redirection url too much?

Do let me know if the question as I've asked it is too confusing for you!

Thanks!

Comment: Share the code that adds the `/auth` to the base url.

Comment: Hmm? What do you mean?

Comment: Or basically, how to import the external backend in without the code going thelinktothebackend//auth/etc & going thelinktothebackend/auth/etc and so on. Thanks!

Comment: I mean *somewhere* in your code, *something* adds `/auth` to your apiBase. That's the important part of your code you should share in your question.

Comment: I see. Thanks! It is basically stuff like async signIn(userData, fail = false){
    const response = await fetch(`${App.apiBase}/auth/signin`, {
      method: 'POST',      
      body: userData
    }) for the sign in page and so on for the other backend items.

Comment: If that's the line, then `App.apiBase` must contain the final `/` somehow... are you sure it wasn't added by mistake?

Comment: Pretty sure. I mean I'm using an external link: this.apiBase = blho-creahaven-backend.herokuapp.com from an uploaded backend server, but when I checked the console log, it rendered it as blho-creahaven-backend.herokuapp.com//auth/etc... instead of blho-creahaven-backend.herokuapp.com/auth/etc

Comment: However, it's can't just appear out of nowhere. Try `console.log(App.apiBase);` I assume it has a slash?

Comment: yeah. It does have the slash.

Comment: I'm assuming you want to try to get rid of the slash. You could hack it inline by using: `fetch(App.apiBase.replace(/\/$/) + '/auth/signin')`, but it's a bit hacky and you mind want try to to figure out what _sets_ `App.apiBase`

Comment: yeah, I used this.apiBase = 'https://blho-creahaven-backend.herokuapp.com/'. And when I went to check on my website's sign in screen, the console log said it's from https://blho-creahaven-backend.herokuapp.com//auth/validate.

Comment: Hiya @Evert, thanks for being so patient with me during the whole troubleshooting process! Turns out I just needed to set the this.apiBase to thisiapiBase = 'myURLhere' without the / and reupload it. It works... somehow. Thanks once again!